# VM in VMWare Workstation keeps changing IP

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

I have a proprietary VM that is Linux based. When I deploy it under VMware Workstation, its IP changes once in a while after reboot (always go up by 1). Both this VM and an Ubuntu VM are deployed under the same host machine uses NAT as network config. But the Ubuntu's VM never changes. I checked the MAC address of my VM and it is the same as the one assigned by VMWare Workstation all along.

I don't want to modify the configuration of the VM as I want it to obtain its network information via DHCP server of VMware Workstation. Any ideas how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Set the static ip address through whichever device is acting as the DHCP server.

Comment: The DHCP server is VMware Workstation. How do you configure DHCP mapping?

Comment: Use the VMware Network Editor to reset your internal network. This will change your settings, but then they should stick. I have 3 NAT machines (1 new, 2 older). The two older ones have not changed IP addresses in months.